# how to properly chain the operations in imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to create the round profile pictures via imagemagick.
I have the following code:

```
convert source.png  \
\( -gravity Center -resize 101x101^ -extent 101x101 \) \
\( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 50,50 50,0.0" \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite dest.png
```

but it ignores the first line where the picture is cropped and resized to 101x101 it only creates the circle in the centre of the original image.

```
convert source.png  \
\( -gravity Center -resize 101x101^ -extent 101x101 \) dest_100.png

convert source.png  \
\( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 50,50 50,0.0" \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite dest.png
```

both of these parts work nicely I just would like to chain it into one command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first resize line get's lost by the sub-process `\(...\)`. Just remove the surrounding parenthesis in the first line, or move the source image into the same parenthesis.

```sh
convert source.png  \
        -gravity Center -resize 101x101^ -extent 101x101 \
        \( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 50,50 50,0.0" \) \
        -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite dest.png
```

*or*

```sh
convert \( source.png  -gravity Center -resize 101x101^ -extent 101x101 \) \
        \( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 50,50 50,0.0" \) \
        -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite dest.png
```